# Progress bar in the center of the Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an Activity whose layout is a FrameLayout in which I swap between 3 fragments.
Each Fragment has a button. When the button is pressed I call a method in the MainActivity which calls async task.
I need to display progress bar in the center for all the 3 fragments when the aysnc task is performed.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start another `Activity` with a transparent background containing the progress bar.

```
<LinearLayout ...
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    ... >

...
```

Comment: how do I close the Activity on postExecute?

Comment: Using [myActivity.finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()).

Comment: i am launching the activity in pre execute: activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, ProgressActivity.class));   where ProgressActivity.class has the progress bar, now I need to close ProgressActivity.class in postExecute

Comment: I had understood, and I gave you the answer in my previous comment.

Comment: I tried giving ProgressActivity.finish(); I am getting error

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult(intent, <requestCode>)` instead and in `onPostExecute()` call [finishActivity(<requestCode>)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity(int)), `requestCode` being the same in both.